# Coda navigator like Espresso code navigator

Tags: dreamweaver, coda, macrabbit-espresso

Can [Coda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_(web_development_software)) do code navigation like [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) or [Dreamweaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) where, if you click a div or any block tag, you can click to see the whole block of code, or collapse the block?

Comment: I'm looking for this too, any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that in Coda, but at least the code navigator works. When working with PHP in Espresso the code navigator nests every method inside the method above it pretty much making code navigation unusable with PHP. I mentioned this to the support team and they responded informing me it cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're talking about is called 'code folding', and is now available in Coda 2, which has recently been released.